# Loop breaks after certain amount of iteration

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a job to do some migration on wordpress sites, although I don't think wordpress has anything to do with my problem. 
So I'm getting a set of data from a table (id, value) which is serialized.

I want to put the serialized data into arrays, according to the function. The algorithm doing everything fine for the first 86 records.

If I run the algorithm on just 86 records I get all the right data instantly. But when I run it 87 or more times its just goes into loading. Doesn't matter how long the max execution time limit is it's still gonna reach it apparently.

I checked the 87th record if theres something odd with it, but nothing i can see. Is there any idea what could couse this?

Here's the code:

```
global $wpdb;

    $houses_built_years = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM bp100_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "epites_eve"');

    foreach ($houses_built_years as $house_built_years) {
        if ($house_built_years->meta_value) {
            $years = unserialize($house_built_years->meta_value);
        } else {
            continue;
        }

        $build = array(array());
        $series = 0; $year = 0;

        while (count($years)) {
            if ($build[$series][$year] && (min($years) - $build[$series][$year] == 1)) {
                $year++;
                $build[$series][$year] = min($years);
                unset($years[array_search(min($years), $years)]);
            } else if ($build[$series][$year]) {
                $year = 0;
                $series++;
                $build[$series][$year] = min($years);
                unset($years[array_search(min($years), $years)]);
            } else {
                $build[$series][$year] = min($years);
                unset($years[array_search(min($years), $years)]);
            }
        }

        $repeater = array();
        foreach ($build as $series) {
            if (count($series) > 1) {
                $repeater[] = $series[0] . ' - ' . $series[count($series) - 1];
            } else {
                $repeater[] = $series[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's some example of records (algoithm breaking at id = 30517):

> 30279
>   1201
>   epites_eve
>   a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1898";}
>
> 30338
>   1202
>   epites_eve
>   a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1891";}
>
> 30397
>   1203
>   epites_eve
>   a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1894";}
>
> 30517
>   1205
>   epites_eve
>   a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1897";}
>
> 30577
>   1206
>   epites_eve
>   a:1:{i:0;s:4:"1891";}

Comment: Could you try starting your script at iteration 86? To see if the issue is related to a row, or to the number of rows processed? Also, could you check server memory during the run?

Comment: Yes I did try it. Its not related to the row, rather the number of rows.

Comment: Is it heavy? have you tested increasing your `memory_limit` ?

Comment: Check your error logs

Comment: In error logs I can only see max_execution_time errors. memory_limit = 1000M is set atm, so it shouldn't be the problem. Also max execution time should not kick in, becouse with 86 records its instant, and with 87 it reaches limit, even if its like 50000s.

Comment: Did you check memory stat during run? If your object are really big, it can fill the memory, and force system to use swap (disk write) and slow everything down

Comment: Its the memory/time after each iteration [memory] => 0.459228515625 [seconds] => 0.0035550594329834

Comment: Do this test: install `htop` to live check memory stats. Then run your script, and check htop values from iteration 0 to 87 to see if there is a peak.